# Get the parent tag along with its position using XML::Smart in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have an XML something like this.

```
my $XML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<TEST>
  <PERSON name="Melissa">
    <PET type="carnivorous">Cat</PET>
    <PET>Dog</PET>
    <AGE>24</AGE>
    <CAR>Y</CAR>
  </PERSON>
  <PERSON name="Thomas">
    <PET type="herbivorous">cow</PET>
    <AGE>28</AGE>
    <CAR>N</CAR>
  </PERSON>
</TEST>
';
```

and here is what i want as result.

```
my $XML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<TEST>
  <PERSON name="Melissa">
    <PET type="carnivorous">Cat</PET>
    <PET>Dog</PET>
    <AGE>24</AGE>
    <CAR>Y</CAR>
  </PERSON>
  <PERSON name="Thomas">
    <PET type="herbivorous">cow</PET>
    <PET type="herbivorous">goat</PET>
    <AGE>28</AGE>
    <CAR>N</CAR>
  </PERSON>
</TEST>
';
```

The steps what i want to follow is :

1.Search the tag of type "herbivorous"

```
my $test_data = XML::Smart->new($XML);
my $Parent_pos=$test_data->{TEST}{PERSON}{PET}('type','eq','herbivorous');
my $new_tag= { type =>"herbivorous" };
```

2.How to insert a new tag " goat " ?? I thought of getting the parent of "cow", and insert a new tag, But I am not able to figure out a way.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't search inside multiple elements at the same time. If you write

```
$test_data->{TEST}{PERSON}{PET}('type', 'eq', 'herbivorous')
```

you are looking in the *first* `PERSON` element in `TEST`, who has no herbivorous pets so you get an empty set returned. Instead, you must loop over all the `PERSON` elements to find one that has a herbivorous pet.

This code looks at each `PERSON` and adds a herbivorous elephant to the end of their list of pets if they already have a herbivorous pet.

```
my $test_data = XML::Smart->new($XML);
my $people = $test_data->{TEST}{PERSON};

for my $person (@$people) {
  my $pets = $person->{PET};
  if ($pets->(qw/ type eq herbivorous /)) {
    push @$pets, { type => 'herbivorous', CONTENT => 'elephant'};
  }
}

print scalar $test_data->data(nometagen => 1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TEST>
  <PERSON name="Melissa">
    <PET type="carnivorous">Cat</PET>
    <PET>Dog</PET>
    <AGE>24</AGE>
    <CAR>Y</CAR>
  </PERSON>
  <PERSON name="Thomas">
    <PET type="herbivorous">cow</PET>
    <PET type="herbivorous">elephant</PET>
    <AGE>28</AGE>
    <CAR>N</CAR>
  </PERSON>
</TEST>
```

Comment: @user2179627: You're welcome. Note that I have changed the `print` statement slightly. In list context, `$xml->data` returns a scond parameter which is a flag indicating whether the data is Unicode text. So you need to add `scalar` to avoid printing a spurious `1` after the XML. Also, you probably don't want the `<?meta name="GENERATOR" ?>` content that `XML::Smart` creates by default, so you need to add a `nometagen => 1` option as well.